# Recoding value labels

Tags: r

r00 and r14 are two datasets im working on. I would like to change value labels in r00 to match those in r14. Although the labels are automatically taken from one of the datasets, I would prefer some consistencies when printing the variables.

The warning that I got from merging two datasets:

Here is my dataset:

```
dput(r00.compressed)
structure(list(econact = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), label = "economic activity", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(`econ active - in employment` = 1, 
    `econ active - unemployed (ilo definition)` = 2, `econ inactive` = 3, 
    `adult - not classifiable (but either unemp or inactive)` = 4, 
    `adult - not classifiable (dk if emp/unemp/inactive)` = 5, 
    `under 16yrs - ineligible for employment questions` = 6), class = c("haven_labelled","vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
    hiqual4 = structure(c(2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 
    1, 4, 2), label = "highest qualification gained - harmonised definition", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(`degree level qualification or above` = 1, 
    `higher edn below degree level (eg hnc, nursing qual)` = 2, 
    `a levels, vocational level 3 & equivlnt (eg as level, nvq 3)` = 3, 
    `o levels, gcse grade a-c, vocational level 2 & equivlnt` = 4, 
    `gcse below grade c, cse, vocational level 1 & equivlnt` = 5, 
    `qualification below gcse/o level (eg trade apprenticeships)` = 6, 
    `other qualification (incl professional, vocational, foreign)` = 7, 
    `qualifications - but dk which` = 8, `qualifications - gcse - but dk grade` = 9, 
    `qualifications - city & guilds - dk level` = 10, `qualifications - other - but dk grade/level` = 11, 
    `no qualifications` = 12, `eligible - no answer` = 13, `under 16yrs - ineligible for qualifications questions` = 14
    ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")),  
    isex = structure(c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
    1, 1), label = "sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(male = 1, 
    female = 2, `dk/na` = 3), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr"

dput(r14.compressed)
structure(list(econact = structure(c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), label = "DV: Economic activity according to the ILO definition -- 3 categories", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(`No answer/refused` = -9, 
`Don't know` = -8, `Interview not achieved` = -7, `Item not applicable` = -1, 
`In employment` = 1, Unemployed = 2, `Economically inactive` = 3, 
`Under 16` = 4), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double"
)), 
hiqual4 = structure(c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), label = "DV: Highest qualification (simplified)", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(`No answer/refused` = -9, 
`Don't know` = -8, `Interview not achieved` = -7, `Schedule not applicable` = -2, 
`Item not applicable` = -1, `Degree or higher` = 1, `Higher education` = 2, 
`A level or equivalent` = 3, Secondary = 4, Other = 5), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
isex = structure(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2), label = "Gender from household grid", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(`No answer/refused` = -9, 
`Don't know` = -8, `Interview not achieved` = -7, `Schedule not applicable` = -2, 
`Item not applicable` = -1, Male = 1, Female = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", 
"vctrs_vctr", "double"))
```

How can I change value labels in r00 to match those in r14?

Comment: "labels" suggests another package such as `haven`, which means that even if we want to try to scrape that data (I don't, too many spaces), we won't have a good representative dataset. Please add sample data using `dput(x)`. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for editing, but please ... always check the code you give us. This fails because you're trying to join `r00` (which is just `"educ"`) with `r14` (also just `"educ"`). Also note that your `educ %>% rename(.)` goes nowhere, you never store it. And you load `haven` but don't use it.

Comment: Still can't run it, but perhaps `full_join(r00, r14, by = "value") |> mutate(label = coalesce(label.y, label.x)) |> select(-label.x, -label.y)`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. value is not actually a column name so I'm not able to merge the data by that. The values and labels are predetermined, by any chance there's any function that allows me to change them?

Comment: I don't use regularly `haven` so I don't know, and the data in the question is not usable.

Comment: I guess I don't understand, what is so difficult about providing `dput(head(r00))` and `dput(head(r14))`? Is it proprietary data? I'm trying to help, but your code to generate data works.

Comment: Apologies... I've provided dput()

Comment: Your warning messages (I don't see any errors in your output, just warnings) say you should check for conflicting value labels. Did you do that?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. `full_join(..., by=NULL)`, and looking at the data I don't know that a merge/join is what you should be trying.

Comment: I am looking for a function that changes my value labels in r00 to match those in r14, how can I do that?

Comment: I did try merge but that gives many duplicated rows. And once the duplicated rows are removed, I'm left with very few observations. Hence why I used full_join

Comment: There are only three columns in common: `c("econact", "hiqual4", "isex")`. Are those the ones you want to relabel?

Comment: Precisely. How may I do so?

Comment: I am still mising a clear explanation, what is the goal/aim of this merge and where lies the problem. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Bernhard, I believe strongly that **it is not a merge**, the attempt of `full_join` is/was a red herring. I think the current subject/title using "recode" is the most applicable to what should be happening. (One _might_ think that "merge those labels with these labels" could be applicable, but even then we aren't merging, we're _overwriting_, so even then ... not a merge. That was red-herring distraction that contributed to hours of looking in the wrong direction, in my opinion.)

Comment: @Victoria, a few comments ago you said *"changes my value labels in r00 to match those in r14"*, that is the statement my answer is addressing. If that's really what you need (and my answer works), it would be ***incredibly useful*** for follow-on readers if your question clearly stated that as the goal, up front, before the verbiage about merging or your attempt to `full_join`. (If I'm incorrect and my answer in its current form is not what you need, then ... I'm still really confused.)

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for the explanation. Voted to close for "needs more clarity".

Comment: No need for an excuse. However, your question will be forever visible one StackOverflow so please correct the question above even if you got a suitable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Up front, this is not a merge/join. We are attempting to relabel individual columns within a frame.

Start by knowing which columns we have in common between the two frames that have labels. There may be a better way to find this, but here goes:

```r
library(haven)
lbls <- intersect(
  names(Filter(c, sapply(r00, is.labelled))),
  names(Filter(c, sapply(r14, is.labelled)))
)
lbls
# [1] "econact" "hiqual4" "isex"
```

With that, assuming `dplyr` (since you tried `full_join`), we can do this (before/after look at `econact`):

```r
library(haven)
library(dplyr)
r00$econact
# <labelled<double>[15]>: economic activity
#  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
# Labels:
#  value                                                   label
#      1                             econ active - in employment
#      2               econ active - unemployed (ilo definition)
#      3                                           econ inactive
#      4 adult - not classifiable (but either unemp or inactive)
#      5     adult - not classifiable (dk if emp/unemp/inactive)
#      6       under 16yrs - ineligible for employment questions
newr00 <- r00 |>
  mutate(
    across(all_of(lbls),
           ~ labelled(.x, attr(r14[[cur_column()]], "labels"))
    )
  )
newr00$econact
# <labelled<double>[15]>
#  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
# Labels:
#  value                  label
#     -9      No answer/refused
#     -8             Don't know
#     -7 Interview not achieved
#     -1    Item not applicable
#      1          In employment
#      2             Unemployed
#      3  Economically inactive
#      4               Under 16
```

The whole data, I'll leave verification of the other two columns up to you.

```r
newr00
#    sn2 sn3 hyear Day leisure a_alone a_notalone econact totpinc hiqual4 livarr dnrkid04 hhtype5 iagegrp isex                 hhtype
# 1   10   1  2000   1       0       1          0       1       6       2      1        0       3       4    2   Married without kids
# 2   10   1  2001   0     380       0          1       1       5       3      1        0       2       4    1 Married with kids <=15
# 3   10   1  2001   1     170       1          0       1       5       3      1        0       2       4    1 Married with kids <=15
# 4   10   1  2001   1     210       0          1       1       5       3      1        0       2       4    1 Married with kids <=15
# 5   10   1  2001   0     190       0          1       1       5       3      1        0       2       4    1 Married with kids <=15
# 6   10   2  2001   0     250       0          1       1       4       3      1        0       2       3    2 Married with kids <=15
# 7  101   1  2000   0     590       1          0       1       2       4      1        0       2       3    2 Married with kids <=15
# 8  101   1  2001   1     340       0          1       1       4       4      1        0       3       4    1   Married without kids
# 9  101   1  2001   1     340       0          1       1       6       2      1        0       3       4    1   Married without kids
# 10 101   1  2001   1     340       0          1       1       5       1      1        0       2       3    2 Married with kids <=15
# 11 101   1  2001   0     150       0          1       1       4       4      1        0       3       4    1   Married without kids
# 12 101   1  2001   0     150       0          1       1       6       2      1        0       3       4    1   Married without kids
# 13 101   1  2001   0     150       0          1       1       5       1      1        0       2       3    2 Married with kids <=15
# 14 101   1  2001   1     470       1          0       1       4       4      1        0       3       4    1   Married without kids
# 15 101   1  2001   1     470       1          0       1       6       2      1        0       3       4    1   Married without kids
```

If you need a base R variant, then this works:

```r
r00[lbls] <- Map(labelled, r00[lbls], lapply(r14[lbls], attr, "labels"))
```

---

Data

```r
r00 <- structure(list(sn2 = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 101), sn3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), hyear = c(2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001), Day = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), leisure = c(0, 380, 170, 210, 190, 250, 590, 340, 340, 340, 150, 150, 150, 470, 470), a_alone = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), a_notalone = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,  0), econact = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), label = "economic activity", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c("econ active - in employment" = 1, "econ active - unemployed (ilo definition)" = 2, "econ inactive" = 3, "adult - not classifiable (but either unemp or inactive)" = 4, "adult - not classifiable (dk if emp/unemp/inactive)" = 5, "under 16yrs - ineligible for employment questions" = 6), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), totpinc = structure(c(6, 5,  5, 5, 5, 4, 2, 4, 6, 5, 4, 6, 5, 4, 6), label = "total net monthly personal income (for employees & self-employed together)", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c("ineligible - not currently employed/ self employed" = -2, "ineligible - under 16yrs" = -1, "             less than £  215" = 1, "£  215 to less than £  435" = 2, "£  435 to less than £  870" = 3, "£  870 to less than £1305" = 4, "£1305 to less than £1740" = 5, "£1740 to less than £2820" = 6, "£2820 to less than £3420" = 7, "£3420 to less than £3830" = 8,  "£3830 to less than £4580" = 9, "£4580 to less than £6670" = 10, "£6670 or more" = 11, "eligible (current employee or self-emp) - dk/ refuse income" = 12), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), hiqual4 = structure(c(2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 2), label = "highest qualification gained - harmonised definition", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c("degree level qualification or above" = 1, "higher edn below degree level (eg hnc, nursing qual)" = 2, "a levels, vocational level 3 & equivlnt (eg as level, nvq 3)" = 3,  "o levels, gcse grade a-c, vocational level 2 & equivlnt" = 4, "gcse below grade c, cse, vocational level 1 & equivlnt" = 5, "qualification below gcse/o level (eg trade apprenticeships)" = 6, "other qualification (incl professional, vocational, foreign)" = 7, "qualifications - but dk which" = 8, "qualifications - gcse - but dk grade" = 9, "qualifications - city & guilds - dk level" = 10, "qualifications - other - but dk grade/level" = 11, "no qualifications" = 12, "eligible - no answer" = 13, "under 16yrs - ineligible for qualifications questions" = 14 ), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), livarr = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), label = "living arrangements (as reported by respondent at q55 & q56 - not based on relat", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c("married  (& living with spouse)" = 1, cohabiting = 2, "single (never married)" = 3, "separated (but still married)" = 4, divorced = 5, widowed = 6, "no answer/ dk" = 7, "under 16yrs - ineligible" = 8), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double" )), dnrkid04 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), hhtype5 = structure(c(3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3), label = "household type - 8 categories", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c("single person household" = 1, "married/cohab couple - with children <= 15" = 2, "married/cohab couple -  no children <= 15" = 3, "single parent  - with children <= 15" = 4, "single parent -   no children <= 15" = 5, "unclassified - married/cohab couples in complex hhlds" = 6, "unclassified - single parents in complex hhlds" = 7,  "other hhlds eg brothers/sisters; unrelated; etc" = 8), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), iagegrp = structure(c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4), label = "age group", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c("8 -15 yrs" = 1, "16 -24 yrs" = 2, "25 -44 yrs" = 3, "45 -64 yrs" = 4, "65 yrs or more" = 5), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), isex = structure(c(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), label = "sex", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c(male = 1,  female = 2, "dk/na" = 3), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), hhtype = c("Married without kids", "Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15", "Married without kids", "Married without kids", "Married with kids <=15", "Married without kids", "Married without kids", "Married with kids <=15", "Married without kids", "Married without kids")), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
r14 <- structure(list(sn3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), sn2 = c(11011212, 11011212, 11011212, 11011212, 11011212, 11011212, 11011212, 11011212, 11011212, 11011212, 11011212, 11011212, 11011212, 11011212, 11011212), hyear = structure(c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015), label = "Interview Year", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c("Interview not achieved" = -7), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), Day = c(1, 0, 0,  1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), leisure = c(120, 510, 510, 120, 120, 510, 120, 510, 120, 510, 510, 510, 510, 120, 120), a_alone = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), a_notalone = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), econact = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), label = "DV: Economic activity according to the ILO definition -- 3 categories", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c("No answer/refused" = -9, "Don't know" = -8, "Interview not achieved" = -7,  "Item not applicable" = -1, "In employment" = 1, Unemployed = 2, "Economically inactive" = 3, "Under 16" = 4), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), SENetPay = structure(c(250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250), label = "Net monthly income based on  earnings last month", format.stata = "%12.0g", labels = c("No answer/refused" = -9, "Don't know" = -8, "Interview not achieved" = -7, "Schedule not applicable" = -2, "Item not applicable" = -1), class = c("haven_labelled",  "vctrs_vctr", "double")), hiqual4 = structure(c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), label = "DV: Highest qualification (simplified)", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c("No answer/refused" = -9, "Don't know" = -8, "Interview not achieved" = -7, "Schedule not applicable" = -2, "Item not applicable" = -1, "Degree or higher" = 1, "Higher education" = 2, "A level or equivalent" = 3, Secondary = 4, Other = 5), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), MarStat = structure(c(3, 3,  3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), label = "Marital status", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c("No answer/refused" = -9, "Don't know" = -8, "Interview not achieved" = -7, "Schedule not applicable" = -2, "Item not applicable" = -1, "Single, never married" = 1, "Cohabiting / living together" = 2, "Married and living with $yourhisher[X] husband/wife" = 3, "A civil partner in a legally recognised same-sex Civil Partn" = 4, "Separated, but still legally married" = 5, Divorced = 6, Widowed = 7, "Separated, but still legally in a same-sex civil partnership" = 8,  "Formerly in a same-sex civil partnership which is now legall" = 9, "Surviving partner from a same-sex civil partnership (civil p" = 10), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), dnrkid04 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), dhhtype = structure(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), label = "DV: Household type -- 8 categories", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c("Single person household" = 1, "Married/cohab couple - with children <= 15" = 2, "Married/cohab couple -  no children <= 15" = 3,  "Single parent  - with children <= 15" = 4, "Single parent -   no children <= 15" = 5, "Unclassified - married/cohab couples in complex hhlds" = 6, "Unclassified - single parents in complex hhlds" = 7, "Other hhlds eg brothers/sisters; unrelated; etc" = 8), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), DVAge = structure(c(41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41), label = "Age", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c("No answer/refused" = -9, "Don't know" = -8, "Interview not achieved" = -7,  "Schedule not applicable" = -2, "Item not applicable" = -1), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), isex = structure(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), label = "Gender from household grid", format.stata = "%8.0g", labels = c("No answer/refused" = -9, "Don't know" = -8, "Interview not achieved" = -7, "Schedule not applicable" = -2, "Item not applicable" = -1, Male = 1, Female = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), totpinc = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), iagegrp = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), hhtype = c("Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15", "Married with kids <=15")), row.names = c(NA,  15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @Victoria, I see that you _unaccepted_ the answer, have you found a case where it does not suffice?